# how to get a value by slicing a dataframe by giving three column names which also includes NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key-value, numpy-slicing

This is the **ohlc dataframe** from which i want to slice the value of **efi**.

```
brick_counts    time_id    efi
   1              nan      1000
   2              nan      1500
   3              nan      2000
   4               2       2500 
   5               2       2600
   6               2       3200
```

To slice a single value from this **ohlc dataframe** i'm using this line of code ,

```
ohlc.loc[(ohlc['brick_counts'] == -5) & (ohlc['time_id'] == 2 ), 'efi'].values[0]
```

This line works perfectly and gives me value but when i try to apply this line for slicing a value using **nan** ,

```
ohlc.loc[(ohlc['brick_counts'] == 5) & (ohlc['time_id'] == float("nan")), 'efi'].values[0]
```

It shows me this error

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

so how shall i slice the value of **efi using brick_counts and nan value of time_id column as my input** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If always exist at least value use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
ohlc.loc[(ohlc['brick_counts'] == 5) & (ohlc['time_id'].isna()), 'efi'].values[0]
```

If possible no match use `next` with `iter`:

```
out = next(iter(ohlc.loc[(ohlc['brick_counts'] == 5000) & (ohlc['time_id'].isna()), 'efi']), 'no match')
```